# Spark Streams: State usage

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I understand that the state can be checkpointed into HDFS and the states can be updated using updateStateByKey OR mapWithState.  Can you please clarify on below?

1) If there are over 500 millions of unique needs to be maintained in a state for a given day, and if an updates come through for 20 million records, would all the 500 million records be brought to the memory, from the checkpointed filesystem?  Also, would it vary between the updateStateByKey OR mapWithState?

2) How does the data gets partitioned within the state?  Can it be controlled, say something like put all 10.00am-11.00am updates into 10.00am partition?

3) Assuming the state is being updated constantly through out the day and there are 500 million unique keys, is there a way to extract (iterate through) all of the state keys/values at a particular point (say once a day) and persist in HDFS/Cassandra?  If so, can you please share an example or provide any that can support this?